# Daily reputation counter. Possible bug.

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

My daily reputation counter on the main site in the "drop down infobox" at the top of the page did not reset from yesterday. So it shows I have 290 rep for "today" which includes the 100 rep I earned yesterday. The reputation information on my user page is correct, though. Has anyone else encountered this anomaly?  Is there anything to be concerned about?

Comment: There is already a meta report filed at Meta StackOverflow [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)

Comment: @KannappanSampath That'll explain it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the way the columns in the profile popup that shows when you hover over your name at the top of the page is implemented is that we just have a column that stores and increases the number throughout the day. Then, at exactly 0:00 UTC, we have a job that sets everyone's daily value to 0, and the increasing begins again.

Unfortunately, last night, there were some, um, issues, and the servers were very unhappy with us. This prevented the column from being reset to 0.

This has been naturally corrected at the UTC rollover just now. We left it as is for today as this isn't very high priority for the work to fix it.